# SQL server Change Column datatype on 1K million records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bigdata

I am facing the column length issue in my table and I want to change column type to `big int` from `int` and table rows around 1K million records but when ever I tried to change data type it is taking to much time and it is eating my machine all space, what is best way and fast way to change the column data type on this big table, currently table has no indexes.

**Currently Column length**

```
ID 4(Length)   10(prec)
```

**Tried**
I added new column and set their datatype to big int and made update query

**Suggestion**

Select insert into newtable is fact way but can we set column type with this query ?

Table Size :

[image: 76268200 74480.66 76260680 74473.32 7520 7.34]

Comment: See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/changing-data-types-large-tables-int-bigint-conundrum/

Comment: You need to minimise the amount of logging that occures in a batch; consider copying data to a new table in multiple batches.

Comment: That red-gate article was an interesting read, though the only different piece I'd do would be to have the cutover to production happen with a schema-swap. Kendra Little has a great article on it, let me know if you cannot find it (it has minimal downtime, though needs a time were a schema lock can be obtained).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved and its takes around less than 2 hours and resolved  by following steps.

- Create empty table with new Column Data type
- Made around 21 batch scripts
- Create clustered index on `big int` column